# Controlling vertical spacing in the upper limit of a 'big' operator

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have the following example which, in my view, has too much spacing between the upper limit of the operator and the operator itself:

[image: Excessive vertical spacing]

(This spacing issue does not occur with Computer Modern, but I am not changing the typeface.)

The source for this example is the following (compiled with LuaLaTeX):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Minion Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_n
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how I might finely control the vertical spacing above the operator? My searches have, so far, been fruitless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can experiment with the font specified spacing parameters, using Stix here as I don't have Minion Math.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_n
\end{equation*}
\everydisplay{
%\Umathlimitabovekern\displaystyle=-25pt
%\Umathlimitabovevgap\displaystyle=-25pt
\Umathlimitabovebgap\displaystyle=-25pt
}

\begin{equation*}
  \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_n
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help; this works beautifully on my end.